# CreateRelationShipTo hangs and previously Saved NOdes too missing

Tags: neo4j

I am facing an unique issue. We are using bojo method to set the properties to the node. After the properties are set, we are creating relationships to created Node. For first Time the Node and relation ships are created and When i save another node it hangs on CreateRelationShipTo line and previously saved node too missing from Neo4j?  Can any one guide us why it was happening?  Sorry for not Providing proper information. The Java code as follows:

```
Transaction trx = DataSource.getGraphDBAPI().beginTx();  
try{
    Node apiDetailsNode = DataSource.getGraphDB().createNode();  
    apiDetailsNode.setId("1");  
    apiDetailsNode.setName("Test API");  
    apiDetailsNode.setURL("www.test.com");  
    parentNode.createRelationshipTo(apiDetailsNode,        
    KnoxxiRelationshipType.API);  
    apiDetailsNode.setStatus("1");
    trx.success();
}catch (Exception e) {
    trx.failure();
    log.error("Strange API Failed To Create");
} finally {trx.finish();}
```

The neo4j Configuration are as follows:

```
node_auto_indexing=true
cache_type=gcr
nodestore_propertystore_mapped_memory_size=150M
nodestore_mapped_memory_size=100M
relationshipstore_mapped_memory_size=500M
strings_mapped_memory_size=150M
nodestore_mapped_memory_size=150M
relationship_auto_indexing=true
```

We have 2M nodes and 8 Million Relationships in our Datastore now.

We are using **1.9.8** Neo4j Version

The last 20 lines on message.log file are as follows:

```
2015-03-20 09:25:08.030+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 385ms [total block time: 5.365s]
2015-03-20 09:25:25.766+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 395ms [total block time: 5.76s]
2015-03-20 09:25:44.909+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 415ms [total block time: 6.175s]
2015-03-20 09:28:46.736+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 377ms [total block time: 6.552s]
2015-03-20 09:28:50.147+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 395ms [total block time: 6.947s]
2015-03-20 09:31:17.876+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 525ms [total block time: 7.472s]
2015-03-20 09:32:50.150+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 424ms [total block time: 7.896s]
2015-03-20 09:35:03.267+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 498ms [total block time: 8.394s]
2015-03-20 09:35:14.967+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 417ms [total block time: 8.811s]
2015-03-20 09:35:20.184+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 402ms [total block time: 9.213s]
2015-03-20 09:37:03.175+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 415ms [total block time: 9.628s]
```

Comment: This question is completely missing context, you don't say which API, which version and don't list any code.

Comment: @MichaelHunger I have added the details requested.

Comment: @MichaelHunger : I have tried the following steps. 
1. Increase the mm size almost double.
2. Increase the Java Heap Size of Glassfish Server. 

Even after both the steps the issue still stands..

Comment: @MichaelHunger: I have found some thing too. When I execute the above Java code, it create & set properties and return the Node Id. I have print the Node ID and access the Neo4j DB via web browser. But the specified query never return any result.
    START root=node(3021432) RETURN root;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the root cause of the issue and fixed it. The reason for hanging is due to Open Transaction connections.(Can be find via JMX Console).

The open connections are happening because of not closing the Execution Result after excecuting the cipher Queries. The sample code are as follows,

```
public static Node executeCypherQuerySingleResult(String strCypherQuery, String strResultColumnName) {
    ExecutionResult result = null;
    Iterator<Node> n_column = null;
    ExecutionEngine engine = null;

    try {

        engine = NeoDbConnection.getExecutionEngine(); // This will return the Execution Engine Instance from Neo DB Connection Singleton Class 
        result = engine.execute(strCypherQuery);
        n_column = result.columnAs(strResultColumnName);
        while (n_column.hasNext()) {
            Node node = n_column.next();
            return node;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Exception on Executing Cypher Query : " + strCypherQuery + ".. Error is : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        // 
        if (null != result) {
            result.close(); // After I add this the issue was solved
        }
        result = null;
        n_column = null;
        engine = null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks for all who guided to solve the issue.